# Setting up OpenGL on Mac and use it on Windows

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glew

For a project at university I need OpenGL. Since we need to run our program on a windows PC I have to code it accordingly (although I have a Mac).

So is there a better tool than XCode (since frameworks like glew are not intended there) ?

And if not - do I only have to include glew- and SDK2-lib?

Comment: Xcode should be fine and there is no reason why you can not use glew - what problem(s) did you encounter ?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend developing on a different platform and then porting to windows (at least not for a university course). Afaik, xcode is not able to cross-compile for windows, so you will end up compiling your code on two different compilers. You'll get a lot of overhead just by making sure that all libraries are correctly compiled for both systems and that you don't write any code that can't be compiled on one of the compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. I opted to run a Windows virtual machine on my Mac.

University computer science departments often have group software licenses that you can use to get free software while you're a student. My university provided access to vmware fusion, Windows 10, and Visual Studio. You should see if your school provides anything.

Performance was an issue for me when I was running more complex scenes in my ray tracer, but that is because I have a Macbook Air that's a few years old already. If you have a more powerful Mac, you should have no trouble at all.

Answer (score -1):

You need: (A) How to create a gl context. (B) How to get function-pointers to gl functions. (C) How to handle user actions (mouse, keyboard). And perhaps (D) some GUI.

(B) is achieved by glew or similar. Not needed on MAC OS, but using it makes no effect at all.

For the rest use SDL, GLFW, etc. Or more complex and featured wxWidgets or Qt.

Comment: That is a terrible simplification of the problem. You should at least mention that there is no way to compile with xcode for windows, so everything that you write has to compile not only under xcode but also with MSVC or mingw. This means that the project setup also has to be done twice unless a system like cmake is used.

Comment: I only would need to compile for test reasons since the code can be tested on a windows in between ..

Comment: I've supposed you already know that Mac classes and functions can not be used in Windows. Only C++ code can be common. That's why I advise using SDL and so on, they have the needed code for each platform.